# How do I loop (for/while/loop) on a Map.Entry

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have a Map.Entry with jSON inside the value, I want make this value to a Map

With Examples it will be easier to explain:
I'm doing an api request to a URL like this:

`response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);`

this is the JSON I get from the request:

```
{"Projects":
  [{"Role":"ProjectAdmin","Url":"http://**/","OverSized":false,"Folders":      
     [{"Name":"sh","Url":"http://**/","Permssion":"rw"}]},
   {"Role":"ProjectAdmin","Url":"http://**/Goooood","OverSized":false,"Folders":     
     [{"Name":"Goooood","Url":"http://**/Goooood","Permssion":"rw"}]}],
 "DeviceToken":"token",
 "TotalProjects":2}
```

This is how I translate the JSON I get to a MAP:

```
ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory()
{
  public List creatArrayContainer() {return new LinkedList();}
  public Map createObjectContainer() {return new LinkedHashMap();}
};
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response1.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
String line;
//TODO:Remove and build a better JSON parser
while (null != (line = br.readLine()))
{
   content.append(line);
}
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();    
try
{
  json = (Map)parser.parse(content.toString(), containerFactory);
  Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

Everything is great now!
now I can do a while on `iter`
like this:

```
while(iter.hasNext())
{
   Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Now My problem is that I have one  `entry.getValue()` that have json in it.

Example:

```
   [{"Role":"ProjectAdmin","Url":"http://**/","OverSized":false,"Folders":      
     [{"Name":"sh","Url":"http://**/","Permssion":"rw"}]},
   {"Role":"ProjectAdmin","Url":"http://**/Goooood","OverSized":false,"Folders":     
     [{"Name":"Goooood","Url":"http://**/Goooood","Permssion":"rw"}]}]
```

And I need to make a Map from it like I did from the response to be able to loop it.
Is there a way to do that ?
Is there a way to do it right?

I don't think it's a problem to make it to a string an reMap it like I did in the start, But I have a feeling there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it is a json and not an ordinary string value? By key? Maybe this helps: http://json.org/java/

Comment: Yeah. It's my api server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to map this code as per your objects

```
 Iterator<Entry<Long, String>> it = 
   yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Long, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<Long, String>) it.next();
        bw.write(pairs.getValue());
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: What I need is that `yourMap` will be the `Map.Entry`.
And Map.Entry don't have entrySet...

Comment: When i defined this map it was like  `Map<Long, String>` can you share how you defined your map

Comment: as you are saying i think you had defined a map inside of a map... :O